# psycopg2 does not work with Serverless framework deployment on AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, psycopg2, serverless-framework

I am trying to make a lambda function connect to Redshift, and deploy the same via The Serverless Framework.

serverless.yml config:

```yaml
pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    dockerFile: ./Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6
RUN yum install -y postgresql-devel postgresql-libs
```

requirements.txt

```
psycopg2==2.8.5
requests==2.22.0
boto3==1.9.234
```

Deployment is done via:

```sh
sls deploy --function fn_name --force
```

AWS Lambda gives an error:

```
libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And I can confirm that it is missing, but when I test the same with local docker image, the file is present. I'm still unsure on how `serverless` actually deploys the package

I do not want to use `psycopg2-binary` and I'm still unsure about `aws-psycopg2`, any suggestions on how to get the code to run?

Comment: The docker image is not identical to the lambda environment. You need to manually include the shared library file `libpq.so.5` in your `serverless.yml`.

Comment: @jellycsc how do you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using this module instead of default one (Supports only Python3.x)

https://pypi.org/project/aws-psycopg2/

While the above is not actively maintained, and has the max version as `psycopg2==2.8.4`, it could serve the use-case you might have.

You can also try zipping and uploading the package from here https://github.com/jkehler/awslambda-psycopg2 if you need support for older python versions.